# How to add payments into the Sale Order Report? Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo, qweb

I want to add payments related to sale.order when printing report.
When printing 'invoice_payments_widget' I got information about payment but,  I got always empty values with : 'payment.amount' and 'payment.date'
What's wrong please ? Any help ?
Here is my code :

```
 <template id="report_saleorder_document_inherit" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
             <xpath expr="//div[@name='so_total_summary']" position="after">
                 
                     <span>payments</span> <p t-field="doc.invoice_ids.invoice_payments_widget"/>
                                          <span>payments</span> <p t-field="doc.invoice_ids.invoice_payments_widget.date"/>
                       <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><strong>Amount</strong></th>
                                    <th><strong>Date</strong></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <t t-foreach="doc.invoice_ids.payment_id" t-as="payment">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span t-field="payment.amount"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span t-field="payment.date" />
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </t>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                </div>
         </xpath>
</template>
```

Thanks.

Comment: can I use this method in sale order report ?? <t t-set="total" t-value="0"/>
<t t-set="payments_vals" t-value="doc.sudo()._get_reconciled_info_JSON_values()"/>
<t t-foreach="payments_vals" t-as="payment_vals">
    <t t-set="total" t-value="total + payment_vals['amount']" />
</t>
<span class="text-nowrap" t-esc="total" />